# Receive SMS per user in Laravel application

Tags: laravel, sms, twilio

In my application, I have about 50 users that need to send and receive SMS. How would I integrate this using Twilio? Do I need a number per user so that when they revive an SMS, I can show it to a specific user only?

The link below shows how to receive SMS, but I need help storing/displaying the SMS to the correct user only.

[Laravel/Twilio Receiving SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50284057/laravel-twilio-receiving-sms)

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/server-notifications-php-laravel

Comment: Will inbound phone numbers *always* go to the same user? Or can that vary?

Comment: No I have around 50-60 users so i think i would need to get a number per user? the users can text any of the clients and the clients should be able to txt to any user.